# textarea in backbone and underscore html decoding the content

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am using [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) with [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

In my template I have the following textarea

```
<textarea id="MyHtml" rows="10" cols="75" name="MyHtml"><%= MyHtml %></textarea>
```

Now the issue is if my model's `MyHtml` has any ascii character it html decodes it and renders it. To know exactly what i mean check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9o6fLL9/).

How do I use the above template and still prevent this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your UnderScore Templates use minus sign ("-") for binding value to your html field instead of equals ("=")
For eg.

```
<textarea id="MyHtml" rows="10" cols="75" name="MyHtml"><%- MyHtml %></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can insert escaped values via `<%- … %>` See http://underscorejs.org/#template

You would write

```
<textarea id="MyHtml" rows="10" cols="75" name="MyHtml"><%- MyHtml %></textarea>
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/7wxrbkw8/